# Date format in Marketing Cloud email based on locale

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date, formatting

I am looking to show the date in two different formats based on locale (the locale variable is set to LocaleCode earlier in the email). For en-US it should be January 1, 2021 and all other locales it should be 1 January, 2021. The actual date is being pulled from a data extension and I have it formatted for en-US currently. What I am trying to do is change the format based on the locale. Here is what I have tried (among other things) but it's still not displaying.

TrialEndDate pulls a date from a data extension: `SET @TrialEndDate = [ExpirationDate]`

```
%%[
 
    IF @locale == "en-US" then
    SET @date=TreatAsContent(FormatDate(@TrialEndDate, "MMMM d, yyyy"))
    ELSE
    SET @date=TreatAsContent(FormatDate(@TrialEndDate, "d MMMM, yyyy"))
    ENDIF
 
]%%
%%=v(@date)=%%
```

I had also tried this, without the `TreatAsContent` function:

```
%%[

    IF @locale == "en-US" then
    SET @date="%%=FormatDate(@TrialEndDate, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%"
    ELSE
    SET @date="%%=FormatDate(@TrialEndDate, "d MMMM, yyyy")=%%"
    ENDIF

]%%
%%=v(@date)=%%
```

Comment: The treatascontent() function isn't needed. And can you update your question with a sample of the what's in`@TrialEndDate`?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Is `[ExpirationDate]` a Date data type?

Comment: Yes. It currently is in the DE as 2021-01-01 12:00 PM but I have reformatted it to display as mentioned in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely wrap your send context personalization strings so you can check for empty.

Also, the pattern for the [day of the month](http://ampscript.guide/formatDate) is `dd`.

I'd recommend something like this:

```ampscript
%%[

  set @debug = 1
  set @trialEndDate = AttributeValue("ExpirationDate")
  set @locale = AttributeValue("locale")

  if @debug == 1 then
    output(concat("<br>trialEndDate: ", @trialEndDate))
    output(concat("<br>locale: ", @locale))
  endif

  if not empty(@trialEndDate) then

    IF @locale == "en-US" then

       SET @date = FormatDate(@TrialEndDate, "MMMM dd, YYYY")

    ELSE

       SET @date = FormatDate(@TrialEndDate, "dd MMMM, YYYY")

    ENDIF

  else

    set @date = "unknown"

  endif

]%%
%%=v(@date)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But won't dd display as 01? The official SF developer documentation has a single 'd' as a token option. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/formatAndFormatDate.htm

Comment: I'd test it with static dates `set @trialEndDate = "2020-10-10"` and `set @trialEndDate = "2020-10-01"`

Comment: Still not having any luck. Does AttributeValue pull the value from the DE? Also, do all the @trialEndDate references need to match when it comes case sensitivity?

Comment: AttributeValue reads values from the send context.  AMPscript is case-insensitive. What is the output from my code?

Comment: There is no output. It is blank.

Comment: If you create a new, blank HTML email with just my code, what shows when you preview against your send audience?